# react-starter-kit simple sqllite example

Tags: express, sequelize.js, graphql-js, react-starter-kit

I'm using the [react-starter-kit](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit)

I am trying to get my head around sequelize, express, sqllite, and [express-graphql](https://github.com/graphql/express-graphql)

There are no examples that I can fine that link the graphql queries in a coherent way with the sequelize models to do some simple reads, yet alone full CRUD. Is there a good **starting** example somewhere that comply with the paragigms of the start kit?

I see the [nodejs-api-starter](https://github.com/kriasoft/nodejs-api-starter) project but it is too big for my needs.